# Getting [object Object] in React when I try to render HTML tag

Tags: reactjs, i18next

I'm trying to render anchor tag `<a>` with the text and link inside of the HTML `<a>` tag. But instead getting `[object Object]` outcome.

I'm using i18N translation to show links text depending on the language.

Code from translate page:

```
export const en = {
  dhl_agreement_terms: 'I agree to {{dhlTerms}}.',
};
```

Here is code from React page:

```
const dhlTerms = <a href="https://dhlExample.com/">DHL Link</a>;

return (
{t('dhl_agreement_terms', {dhlTerms: dhlTerms,})}
)
```

I m getting this result:

[image]

Comment: `dhlTerms` is a React element. `t` has no idea how to serialize that into `'I agree to {{dhlTerms}}.'` (and certainly not how to run it as React), so you get the default `[object Object]`.

Comment: How can i use <a> tag and show link in my react?

Comment: As a React element I doubt you can. Maybe you could use a regular string and set it as the innerHtml of wherever that value is going.

Comment: You'll have to keep the link out of the translation. `dhl_agreement_terms: 'I agree to'` and `return <span>{t('dhl_agreement_terms')} {dhlTerms}.</span>`

Comment: Are you using `react-i18next`? `<Trans>` allows for component interpolation.